# Can I install OS X Leopard on the following configuration?

Tags: macos, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Mac OS X on customized hardware?](https://superuser.com/questions/24624/is-it-possible-to-install-mac-os-x-on-customized-hardware)

I have problem in installing Apple OS X Leopard on my Laptop.

The company is "Zenith". Model is "Admiral plus". 
H/W Configuration is:

- Intel Core 2 Duo processor
- 2.0 Ghz
- 4GB RAM
- 320 Hardisk
- 3MB Cache
- Intel original Motherboard.

If any one of you have Idead then please share with me.
Thanks a lot..

Comment: This question is more appropriate for SuperUser.  After a few more close votes, it will be migrated automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to install Mac OS X on customized hardware?](http://superuser.com/questions/24624/is-it-possible-to-install-mac-os-x-on-customized-hardware) (or "Too localized" otherwise?)

Answer (score 4):

**No, you cannot install Mac OS X on non-Apple hardware.** Two reasons:

1. Presumably the version of Mac OS X that you have (if you obtained it legally) is only going to boot and install on a Macintosh. Hacks exist (such as the OS X x86 project), but they're not supported, not guaranteed to work, and require a number of additional steps on your part.
2. This is expressly forbidden by Apple's licensing agreement, to which you must agree in order to install OS X. Whether or not that's binding in your country is up to you and a lawyer to determine.

Have you tried [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download)? Or if you need to run Mac OS X, the [MacBook](http://www.apple.com/macbook/) is excellent and affordable.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with alternatives, such as "Ubuntu". Answer 1 is true, answer 2 is off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted. I guess it's your fault that Apple sells Mac OS X that way.

Comment: @TFM: Notice that, as you pointed out, I **do** provide an explicit answer to the question. Strictly speaking, of course it has nothing to do with alternatives. I just thought providing one might be helpful (or at least, I would appreciate it), since the actual answer to the question may have stopped the asker dead in his tracks. Additionally, answer 2 is *far* from off-topic. Maybe you don't care about adherence to licensing agreements, but that's your prerogative, and I even allowed for that situation. It's still worth knowing about and necessary detail for a complete answer to the question.

Answer (score -2):

Technically, installing Mac OSX on anything but a Mac is a violation of the EULA.

Legally, EULAs haven't been proven actionable.

Whether or not it will work on that hardware, irrespective of the legality... check out www.hackint0sh.org as the place to go. This isn't a SO question.

Comment: You need to be *very careful* with blanket statements like "Legally, EULAs have't been proven actionable." In the US, they **most certainly have**. (Although, in certain other cases, they have also not. It's still a legally "grey" area. But either way, your statement is wrong.)

Comment: How can it be "techically illegal"? Technically = Possible. Legally = Not.